# Проверка покупок в Google Play

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-play, in-app-purchases

Всем привет! Хотел спросить о проверке покупок в приложении. Всегда ли нужно проверять их на сервере или локально тоже надежно? К примеру можно ли взломать подобную проверку: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27032472/4014042